# React-native, Firebase network error while trying to log in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I've followed a React-native login tutorial using Firebase, I use [create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app) for easy dev(my [package.json](https://pastebin.com/rjvfjL3E)), I'm using NodeJS `v6.10.1`, I'm using Note 4 Device(4.4.4), I enabled `Email/Password` authentication within Firebase console, for some reason I get:

```
{
    code: "auth/network-request-failed",
    message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."
}
```

I didn't forgot to use `firebase.initializeApp` and my code is:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.catch(e0 => {
  console.log(e0);
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(e1 => {
      console.log(e1);
      this.setState({ error: 'Authentication Failed.' });
    });
});
```

For both I get the same error object.

Comment: Try again now.. i have seen multiple times that you get random network errors which disappear after a while

Comment: @ChristopherRivera I've tried, unfortunately same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the problem was:

It all starts by this `Debugger and device times have drifted by more than 60s`, due to other, adb related problem I couldn't run `adb shell "date -s`date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S`"`, after I fixed my adb problem I run `adb shell "date -s`date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S`"`, now the Firebase error was saying: `such as timeout`, adb(my computer) time was -4min than the device, so to fix that I changed the time on my computer, adding 4min so it will match the device time.

**What I assume was the problem, I'm not a networks expert so please if anyone can fix some of my assumptions if there is something wrong:**

**For explanation I just use unreal stuff(`reqTimestamp`,...), but the concept is valid(I hope):**

The **device** signed the request with a timestamp and a timeout, for example, reqTimestamp=`22:16`, reqTimeout=`22:17`, my device is connected throught my wifi, so when the modem connected to my computer, a basic check on my computer or internally the modem, such as: `if(reqTimeout > timeNow) reject`, could prevent the request from even leave my network so Firebase issue this generic error regarding network problem.

Comment: I have the same Error But i dont understand anything in this solution..Please clarify. Thank you

Comment: @henrybbosa First, if you can run `adb shell "date -s date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S` do it, in my case I had to fix an unrelated error that wouldn't let me run the line above, after I fixed the problem, I was able to run the line above and it partially fixed my problem as I got an `such as timeout`(I assume it's part of the text) error, to fix that I change the time on my machine, as you can see I've stated that my computed had -4min from the device, tell me if you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error for a react-native project running using expo on an android device emulator(on windows).

I know this will sound weird but in my case I was getting this error when using internet from my phone's hotspot. When I switched to my normal wi-fi internet connection, the error went away.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error.
In my case it caused by more then one identifier for the same email in Firebase -> Authentication.
Do not know why I have more than one record for the same email, but after deleting all and login again. The problem is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I connected to a VPN, the error went away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).